# Include Dynamically-Referenced Assembly with No Public Classes

Tags: blazor, .net-standard-2.0

I have a client-side Blazor project which references the nuget package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features`. I am attempting to load it via MEF:

```
var lAssemblies = new[]
{
    Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis"),
    Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp"),
    Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features"),
    Assembly.Load("Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features"),
}.Concat(MefHostServices.DefaultAssemblies).Distinct().ToArray();
var lHost = MefHostServices.Create(lAssemblies);
```

At runtime, the first three assemblies I explicitly load are found just fine, but I cannot load `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features`.

```
WASM: [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] Could not load the file 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features'.
WASM:   at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Boolean refonly) <0x4ac92d8 + 0x00070> in <b1ad3c5cea744bd399337592aed7f58e>:0 
WASM:   at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString) <0x4ac9290 + 0x00014> in <b1ad3c5cea744bd399337592aed7f58e>:0 
WASM:   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.String assemblyString) <0x4ac91c8 + 0x00010> in <b1ad3c5cea744bd399337592aed7f58e>:0
```

Normally I would solve this by adding a `typeof(Some.Type.In.The.Assembly)`, but this assembly does not have any public types. How can I force the compiled output to include this assembly?

Note: I did try accessing it directly through the browser also, just to see if it is even there (`/_framework/_bin/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.dll`). This results in a 404 error.